# Combining InstanceContextMode.Single and InstanceContextMode.PerCall/PerSession functionalities

Tags: c#, wcf, service, instantiation

The problem I am having is that none of the "InstanceContextMode" options seem to provide the flexibility I require. Maybe there is some trick I can apply, but I cannot think of anything tidy enough.
Here is what I am trying to do:
- I want to be able to have multiple clients using the same service instance (ie. InstanceContextMode.Single)
- But I also want to be able to create multiple session instances (ie. some of the clients will interact with different instances of my service - InstanceContextMode.PerSession)

For instance:
- Client A, B and C talk to service1 instance 1
- Client D and E talk to service1 instance 2

Comment: It might make more sense to have different clients call different endpoints. It might also make sense if instead of managing whether the service is per instance or per session, maybe you need to manage whether certain dependencies used within the service are per instance or per session. That way instead of trying to control how service instances are created you control how your dependencies are created. It's easier to have more granular control over that.

Comment: Not too sure what you mean by "using different endpoints". Each endpoint will still be pointing to the same WCF service, so how does that help with instantiation? Each session is and should be completely decoupled, so adding granularity from within each session is difficult.